# What is the easiest way to solve this integral with u-subsitition or what are other methods should be used?

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you calculate this integral?

[image]

Comment: The symmetry of the visual representation should suggest that this curve splits the area in half, so the integral is half the area of the square.  To show it's EXACTLY symmetric, use trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gigantic hint: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^{45}(x)}{\sin^{45}(x)+\cos^{45}(x)}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^{45}(x)}{\sin^{45}(x)+\cos^{45}(x)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ How are those two integrals related? (think u-substitution)

Comment: so you are definitely not taking sin^45+cos^45 as u? I'm sort of lost

Comment: Could you show that the two integrals are equal to each other? In other words, can you transform one into the other using a u-substitution?

Comment: By the way this is basically a trick question, a standard problem on contest sheets and stuff like that... it'll seem obvious once you see the trick.

Comment: Does this method have a name I can study more about it? by seeing more examples?

Comment: @MonaJalal : Let $u=\pi/2-x$ so that $du=-dx$.  Then $\sin(x) = \sin(\pi/2-u) = \cos(u)$ and similarly $\cos(x)=\sin(u)$.  As $x$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$, then $u$ goes from $\pi/2$ to $0$, so you have $\displaystyle\int_{\pi/2}^0\cdots\cdots(-du)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cdots\cdots\,du$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Aren't you a math editor on Wikipedia?? You should comment on my question about that...

Comment: Yes! the "Gigantic hint" of user140943 is perfect!